# can't find variable veiw

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following code from a tutorial on youtube (im just getting started with react native):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


type Props = {};
export default class Main extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Veiw style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                Todo List
            </Text>
        </Veiw>

        <ScrollView style={style.ScrollContainer}>


        </ScrollView>

        <Veiw style={style.footer}>
            <TextInput styles={styles.TextInput} placeholder='>Todo' placeholder = 'white' underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'>

            </TextInput>
        </Veiw>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but when i run this on my android emulator i get the following error message:

ReferrenceError can't find variable: Veiw

I know that the error is prity clear, but i imported Veiw in the start of the app, so why isn't it registered?

Comment: You just didn't imported "Veiw", you imported "View", which is the right way to write it.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the most useful answer as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a typo, this happens sometimes, just change "Veiw" to "View". Since you are new to React Native you can always head over to the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view) and be sure that the components you are working with actually exist when importing them (the official components are always imported in the "import 'react-native'" line).

All of these are official components of React Native:

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
```

In the docs you will always find the components, their props, and how they can be used. Also there are some useful guidelines there, I suggest you start with them as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you spelt 'view' wrong, Try this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


    type Props = {};
    export default class Main extends Component<Props> {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                    Todo List
                </Text>
            </View>

            <ScrollView style={style.ScrollContainer}>


            </ScrollView>

            <View style={style.footer}>
                <TextInput styles={styles.TextInput} placeholder='>Todo' placeholder = 'white' underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'>

                </TextInput>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled View in four places, fixing it would get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

just you should change veiw to View.